# Helm point repository to monorepo package?

Tags: git, repository, monorepo, kubernetes-helm

I'm attempting to setup a helm chart, but I am a programmer and have no idea what I'm doing.

It seems by default the helm chart points to a *repository*, which I'm guessing is the GIT repo for the project that will be launched into Kubernetes.

I'm assuming helm will fetch that repository during the install process.

How would you set this field when using a monorepo where each package is a folder within the repository, instead of a repository itself?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah,  your charts have to live somewhere.  If you run k8 in AWS, s3 makes a lot of sense ( although my work just stores them in github)

https://andrewlock.net/how-to-create-a-helm-chart-repository-using-amazon-s3/

helm search test